# Answer or comments and search engine impact?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, search

Some questions can be rapidly (and efficiently) answered using the comments only.

But is doing that (instead of providing an answer in the answers part) influences the search engine later?

The idea behind this question is about the efficiency of future researches on the question's subject (and so for instance, the amount of duplicate questions later).

Comment: I don't know about search engines, but as far as I understand, answering with a comment makes the question remain unanswered, and will keep popping back to the main page until there is an accepted answer or an answer with votes.

Comment: Google is probably intelligent enough to down-ranks questions that have no answers or low scores in search results too.